# install/manage ntp on ubuntu 11.04 using puppet

Tags: puppet

I have looked at some of the puppet-ntp packages on git and other places, but its not clear on exactly HOW they would be installed. It seems most of them are focused on a puppet server pushing ntp or ntpd to clients. But what if i have just ONE host, which i want to manage, and have NO puppet server. so in that case can i use:

```
package { 'ntp':    ensure => 'installed', }
```

If so , then at least puppet site should mention it. The idea is to have this package in a ntp.pp file and run puppet apply ntp.pp command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what was your intent of asking this question but if you just want to use puppet to install just a package, you can also use:

```
puppet resource package ntp ensure=present
```